# boost::spirit and grammars

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to parse this simply and consise xml-minded structure with Boost::Spirit,

```
One{
    Two{
        Three{
        }
    }
}
```

And the code is organized as follows:

Struct definition to keep the spirit-stuff:

```
struct config;
typedef boost::variant< boost::recursive_wrapper<config> , std::string > config_node;

struct config
{
    std::string name;
    std::vector<config_node> children; 
};


BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    config,
    (std::string, name)
    (std::vector<config_node>, children)
)
```

( shameless stealed from the xml intro )

Declaration of the rules ( on the parser class )

```
qi::rule<Iterator, config(), qi::locals<std::string>, ascii::space_type> cfg;
qi::rule<Iterator, config_node(), ascii::space_type> node;
qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> start_tag;
qi::rule<Iterator, void(std::string), ascii::space_type> end_tag;
```

Definition of the rules, in the parser 'parse' method.

```
    node = cfg;
    start_tag =  +(char_ -'{') >> '{';
    end_tag = char_('}');

    cfg %=  start_tag[_a = _1]
        >>  *node
        >>  end_tag(_a);
```

_a and _1 are boost::phoenix variables.

This rules works for the small snipped pasted above, but if I change it to:

```
One{
    Two{
    }
    Three{
    }
}
```

( two groups in the same scope, instead of group inside of other group  ) the parser fails.
and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, your code seems like a simplified version of [mini_xml2.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/mini_xml2.cpp) from Boost's tutorial (aka "the shamelessly stolen one").

To make your example work, you'd have to change the line:

```
start_tag =  +(char_ -'{') >> '{';
```

to

`start_tag =  +(char_ -'{' - '}') >> '{';`

It's pretty self-explanatory now:) Whenever the parser parses a `start_tag`, it starts looking for `node`s (because of the `>>  *node` part). Since `}` is a legal `start_tag`, it may be recognized as one, and it shouldn't.

---

btw There are a few redundancies in your code that you might consider fixing. For instance:

In the original mini_xml2.cpp example, `end_tag` served as a function checking that you close the same tag as the one opened (hence the signature `void(std::string)`). You'd be better off with

```
cfg %=  start_tag[_a = _1]
>> *node
>> "}";
```

---

The nodes in the mini_xml2.cpp example where polymorphic, so `boost::variant` was used along with the visitors. In your example this is also redundant. Honestly, it makes me wonder how the line

```
node = cfg
```

didn't cause any problems during compilation, since `node` has a `boost::variant` type. FYI, in the original example this line was:

```
node %= xml | text;
```

and the `%=` operator correctly 'guessed' the type of the RHS, since the `|` operator reads the result as `boost::variant`.

Comment: Thanks. The boost is a huge monster, and I`m still trying to `tame` it. =)